# biblatex/ no pagetotal in footnotes

Tags: biblatex

I'm working with

```
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-trad2, bibstyle=verbose-trad2, citepages=omit]{biblatex}
```

I don't want to show `pagetotal` for books in the footnotes, but only in the final bibliography. I know that I can use the `authortitle` style but I need to keep the following fields: adress, publisher and year.

Does someone know how I can get that with XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modification of the `cite:full:citepages` macro for `citepages=omit` will always suppress `pagetotal` in citations.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad2, citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
    and
    test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
  }
    {\clearfield{pages}}
    {}}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
lorem \autocite{companion}

ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin. The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1994.]

A slightly quicker alternative that is not restricted to just the cases where it is necessary to delete the field would be

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pagetotal}}
```

if you don't need the field at all, use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagetotal, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you !